# jQuery animate relative position (on hover) bug,

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Whenever the following code is run in Chrome and FF (not tested in other browsers), the `"text"` goes as such , as in the image.
The script is supposed to lift the `"text"` 4px above on `mouseover` and return it back on `mouseout`

But instead when the mouse is brought in the motion as below, each time it lifts 4px above to its last position.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#n #c a').hover(function(){
        $('span',this).stop(true,true).animate({top:'-=4px'},200);
    },function(){
        $('span',this).stop(true,true).animate({top:'+=4px'},400);
    });
});
```

[image: Follow the steps as such, it should be quick!]

NOTE : In above image the text is just one, others are shown for understanding purpose.
You have to be quick to catch the same effect.

Comment: @Val try it very quick, like swirling motion around the link...

Comment: oh ok I get it lol :) btw "-=4px" I think is to increment something by 4px just like you would use `i++;` inc by 1 in this case it means `top+4px", and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just set the top to -4px on hover and 0px when the mouse exists

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#n #c a').hover(function(){
        $('span',this).stop(true,true).animate({top:'-4px'},200);
    },function(){
        $('span',this).stop(true,true).animate({top:'0px'},400);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, :-) its better now!, although still it lifts up, but at-least it returns back to its original position.

Comment: Can there be still any chance that the text could be restricted to particular area and thus if tries to cross it it bounces back to its original position?

Comment: You could also go the css3 way with something like:
`#c a 
{    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#c a:hover {margin-top:-4px;}`